# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value in Windows Form

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am working on a program that takes the values of the columns of the table created in mssm into the datagrid, among these columns are columns with dates. In Microsoft SQL Server,the date is written as "1986-09-19 00:00:00.000", and in visual studio as "02.12.2022 0:00:00". How to get rid of this error? Convert these types into a single one?

```
            dgw.Rows.Add(record.GetString(0), record.GetString(1), record.GetInt32(2), record.GetString(3), record.GetString(4), record.GetInt32(5), record.GetInt32(6), record.GetString(7), *record.GetDateTime(8)*, RowState.ModifiedNew);
```

```
                var pub_date = dataGridView_Book.Rows[index].Cells[8].Value.ToString(); //

                var changeQuery = $"UPDATE Book SET Title_book = '{Title}', pages = '{pages}', language_book = '{lang}', format_book = '{format}', ID_Genre = '{genre}', ID_publishing_house = '{public_house}', FILE_path = '{file_path}', Publication_date = '{pub_date}' WHERE ISBN = '{ISBN}'";
                var command = new SqlCommand(changeQuery, database.getConnection());
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

```
[date in sql][1]
[date in Visual Studio][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eajLS.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/25TVN.jpg
```

Comment: Don't store dates as text to begin with. Don't use string interpolation or concatenation to construct SQL queries from input either. That's how conversion errors like this and SQL injection problems occur. Use query parameters to pass dates, strings, numbers etc as strongly type parameter values outside the query itself

Comment: Can you imagine what would happen if one of those fields contained `'; Drop Table Students; --` ? ?

Comment: I would look for bad data. Th error is that it can't covert a varchar value to a datetime - it tried to convert the varchar value but the result of the conversion didn't fit in a datetime.  The most common culprit is bad data in the varchar column, so look there. Also, read the comments about choosing a correct data type - if the column is indeed a datetime, then don't store it in a varchar and you can help prevent these things from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always, always, use strongly-typed parameters when communicating with the database. The GUI front-end can take a string and then should convert it to the proper data-type such as a datetime in your question. The GUI alerts the user if there is a problem converting the string.

```
//Handle the GUI datetime string. Convert to a datetime field.
DateTime pub_date = DateTime.MinValue;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(
    dataGridView_Book.Rows[index].Cells[8].Value.ToString(),
    out pub_date
    ))
{
    //Handle the error (alert the user) if string doesn't parse to a datetime.
}

string changeQuery = "UPDATE Book SET Title_book = @Title, pages = @Pages, language_book = @Lang, format_book = @Format, ID_Genre = @Genre, ID_publishing_house = @PublishingHouse, FILE_path = @FilePath, Publication_date = @PublicationDate WHERE ISBN = @ISBN";
var command = new SqlCommand(changeQuery, database.getConnection());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", Title);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublicationDate", pub_date);

//Or better yet, specify the dbType for the parameter.
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PublicationDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = pub_date;

... // Add rest of parameters.
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```